# Can`t add new item to context menu in Chrome (manifest 3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have face some difficulties during Manifest 3 to Manifest 3 migration: nothing works.
I have developed a simple **Chrome extension** that adds a new item in the context menu, so you can search the inserted text in some website. It works correctly in the manifest 2, but not in the 3rd.
So there is manifest code (3)

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "name",
  "short_name": "shortN",
  "description": "This extension will work someday I hope so",
  "background": [{
    "service_worker": [ "background.js" ]
  }],
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/128.png",
    "48": "icons/48.png",
    "32": "icons/32.png",
    "16": "icons/16.png"
  },
  "permissions": [ "contextMenus", "tabs", "activeTab" ],
  "version": "1.3"
}
```

And a sample of background code

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: "title",
        contexts: ["selection"],
        id: "title1"
    });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "title1") {
        let getToSite = "https://*" + info.selectionText
        chrome.tabs.create({index: tab.index + 1, url: getQ, selected: true});
    }
})
```

Can someone take a look and say what`s wrong with it? I`m also new to JS (like, three-days-new), so I do appreciate simple explanations
Thank you!

Comment: Remove all four `[` and `]` in your `background` section.

Answer (score 1):

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
```

"service_worker" is a  string ,
no [ ]